# Getting a total from multiple rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, addition, multiple-columns

I am not very good at MySQL queries. Can someone help me figure out how to do this?

I have a table like this (lets call it **stats**):

```
+----+-------+-----+
| id | memid | qty |
+----+-------+-----+
| 1  | 99    | 0   |
+----+-------+-----+
| 2  | 102   | 22  |
+----+-------+-----+
| 3  | 102   | 10  |
+----+-------+-----+
| 4  | 99    | 100 |
+----+-------+-----+
| 5  | 17    | 25  |
+----+-------+-----+
| 6  | 87    | 72  |
+----+-------+-----+
| 7  | 36    | 0   |
+----+-------+-----+
| 8  | 102   | 6   |
+----+-------+-----+
```

I need a MySQL query that will combine the `qty` of all the `memids` and `ORDER BY ASC` the total `qty` for each `memid`.

Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, but please remember to not belittle people when posting comments.  Don't assume I didn't try things first.  If you don't want to respond then don't.   Please don't respond any more, I don't want to bother you with my trivial matters.

Comment: We can only go by what you posted in the question. If you did try something first, you should have posted it here, so we could help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select `SUM` as another field in query and order it by qty, e.g.:

```
SELECT id, memid, qty, SUM(qty)
FROM table
ORDER BY qty;
```

Please note that `SUM` will return the same value for all the rows as it will be a constant value.

If you have multiple records per `memid` and want to calculate `SUM` per memid then you can use `GROUP BY` e.g.:

```
SELECT memid, SUM(qty) AS `sum`
FROM table
GROUP BY memid
ORDER BY sum;
```

Comment: This will just return one row since you have no `GROUP BY`.

Comment: He wants the sum for each `memid`. `id` is probably the primary key and unique.

Comment: @Barmar OP has specifically mentioned to `combine the qty of all the memids` so I have intentionally not added `GROUP BY`. I have added another answer anyway.

Comment: @Barmar updated the answer, yes that might be the case.

Comment: @DarshanMehta Thanks!  Sometimes it is hard to wrap your head around things.  Its nice to have a kind person to point the way.  This was what I needed. :)